# How to use typeDORM with NestJS and AWS Lambda

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, nestjs, serverless-framework

I'm trying to build a NestJS project and use typeDORM to save and receive items from DynamoDB. Ultimately the app should be deployed as a AWS Lambda. For local testing I am using `serverless offline`.

Here is a project to demonstrate my problem: https://github.com/m-kotek/serverless-typedorm

**What's the Problem?** 
If the app is started with `serverless offline start` or `serverless invoke local -f main` the Lambda crashes.

I followed the instructions on [typeDORM's github](https://github.com/typedorm/typedorm) and called `createConnection()` in `main.ts`. However if `getEntityManager()` now is executed by `app.service.ts`'s constructor the output is as follows:

```
[Nest] 24576  - 23.11.2022, 19:36:20     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 24576  - 23.11.2022, 19:36:20   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] No such connection with name "default" exists
✖ Lambda timeout.
```

I also tried a Singleton-pattern approach, where the entityManager is initialized and then exported in `main.ts`. This led to following output:

**Output with serverless offline start**

```
[Nest] 25733  - 23.11.2022, 19:47:11     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 25733  - 23.11.2022, 19:47:11   ERROR [ExceptionHandler]
✖ Lambda timeout.
```

**Output with serverless invoke local -f main**

```
[Nest] 26873  - 23.11.2022, 20:47:22     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application... +2ms
[Nest] 26873  - 23.11.2022, 20:47:22   ERROR [ExceptionHandler]
TypeError
at Reflect.getMetadata (/home/mon/Desktop/api-master-serverless/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:354:23)
at DependenciesScanner.isInjectable (/home/mon/Desktop/api-master-serverless/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:302:26)
at DependenciesScanner.insertModule (/home/mon/Desktop/api-master-serverless/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:73:18)
at DependenciesScanner.scanForModules (/home/mon/Desktop/api-master-serverless/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:34:43)
at DependenciesScanner.scan (/home/mon/Desktop/api-master-serverless/node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:27:20)
at async /home/mon/Desktop/api-master-serverless/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:95:17
at async Function.asyncRun (/home/mon/Desktop/api-master-serverless/node_modules/@nestjs/core/errors/exceptions-zone.js:22:13)
at async NestFactoryStatic.initialize (/home/mon/Desktop/api-master-serverless/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:94:13)
at async NestFactoryStatic.create (/home/mon/Desktop/api-master-serverless/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-factory.js:37:9)
at async bootstrap (/home/mon/Desktop/api-master-serverless/dist/main.js:33:17)
```

main.ts:

```
const documentClient = new DocumentClientV3(new DynamoDBClient({}));

export const masterTable = new Table({
  name: 'master',
  partitionKey: 'PK',
  sortKey: 'SK',
});

export let entityManager: EntityManager = null;

async function bootstrap() {
  config.update({
    region: '--',
    accessKeyId: '--',
    secretAccessKey: '--',
    signatureVersion: '--',
  });

  createConnection({
    table: masterTable,
    name: 'default',
    entities: [Organization],
    documentClient,
  });

  entityManager = getEntityManager();

  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

I tried importing 'reflect-metadata' in index.ts, main.ts and in both at the same time resulting in the same output.

Anyone faced this behavior before?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. I did exactly what you did above but with the following configuration:

```
const documentClient = new DocumentClientV3(new DynamoDBClient({
    region: "local",
    endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
}));

config.update({
    region: "local",
    dynamodb: {
        endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
    }
})
```

Note:
I also ran dynamodb locally. Please follow the instructions to run dynamodb locally here: [Deploying DynamoDB locally on your computer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html)

Answer (score 0):

To use tyoeDORM with nestJS, you can try out my package here https://github.com/nest-dynamodb/typedorm. In this way, you can inject TypeDORM as a singleton provider in your app.

First, install it

```bash
npm install --save @nest-dynamodb/typedorm
```

or

```bash
yarn add @nest-dynamodb/typedorm
```

Your app.module.ts will look like this, inject the typeDorm as an imported module.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeDormModule } from '@nest-dynamodb/typedorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeDormModule.forRoot({
        table,
        entities: [],
        documentClient: new DocumentClientV3(new DynamoDBClient({})),
        name: instanceName
      }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

to use the typeDorm connection in your service or controller:

```
import { Controller, Get, } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectTypeDorm, TypeDormConnection } from '@nest-dynamodb/typedorm';
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(
    @InjectTypeDorm() private readonly connection: TypeDormConnection,
  ) {}
  @Get()
  async getHello() {
    const item = await this.connection.entityManager.findOne(...);
    return { item };
  }
}
```

the typeDorm module is a global module so that you can inject it into your app module and use it everywhere.

Please feel free to open issues or PRs if there's any problem.